# How can you remove another modules events?

Tags: commerce, event-subscribers

So, I have an event subscriber for Drupal commerce that listens for "commerce_order.place.post_transition" and will send a bespoke order email (due to not being able to change some of the things like subject title in the commerce module).

Commerce also has an event subscriber listening to "commerce_order.place.post_transition" which will send an order receipt email. I need to unsubscribe this event to prevent sending duplicate emails but searching through google and comments sections of articles has lead me to a dead end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the event subcriber service from the container:

*my_module/src/MyModuleServiceProvider.php*

```
namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

/**
 * Remove the foo event subscriber.
 */
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $container->removeDefinition('foo_event_subscriber'); 
  }

}
```

You find the service name in the *MODULE.services.yml* file of the other module.

More info https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services

Comment: Cheers, this worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question specifically but is an alternative. If it's the standard commerce email you could go to "Commerce > configuration > Orders > Order types" and within each order type you can control to "Email the customer a receipt when an order is placed"

Comment: Yeah, my current workaround is to untick that, which prevents commerce from sending emails and makes our bespoke event subscriber the only one to send emails. Unfortunately it is easy for any member of the admin to team to tick that box again and start sending duplicate emails.

Comment: You might find it easier to form_alter and prevent that option being ticked rather than disabling the subscriber

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the existing event as described in this article: https://matthieuscarset.com/en/blog/how-safely-override-or-extend-other-services-methods-drupal-8

In mymodule/src/EventSubscriber/MySubscriber.php:

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

class MySubscriber extends ParentSubscriber {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function decoratedMethod(...$args) {
    parent::decoratedMethod(...$args); // or whatever you want to do
  }
}
```

In mymodule/mymodule.services.yml:

```
services:
  mymodule.myservice:
    public: false
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\mySubscriber
    decorates: decorated_provider.decorated_service_name
```

Answer (score -2):

and welcome to Drupal Answers.

Assuming you're using Drupal 8, you may try the below code to hide the email fieldset:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "commerce_order_type_edit_form") {
        $form["emails"] = [
            "#checked" => FALSE,
        ];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The question is about events, not form alters.